# How to use if condition in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

You are given a table, Triangles, containing three columns: A, B and C. Each row of the table denotes the length of the three sides of a triangle.

Write a query to find the type of each triangle based on side lengths. Output one of the following statements for each row entry in the table:

- Not A Triangle: If the given values of A, B and C don't form a triangle.
- Equilateral: If the triangle is equilateral. (All 3 sides are equal in length)
- Isosceles: If the triangle is isosceles. (2 sides are equal in length)
- Scalene: If the triangle is scalene. (All 3 sides have differing lengths)

Sample Input

Sample Output

Isosceles  Equilateral  Scalene  Not A Triangle

Comment: This appears to be a homework problem. What did you try so far? Have you looked at CASE statement?

Comment: Lazy student's homework?

Comment: I unable to find how to  do it.I am new in sql ,so i was prcticing.pls help.

Answer (score 1):

Look up the documentation on `case` / `when`. This will solve your problem, because it will handle several conditions in sequence (like a `switch` / `case`), and this is what you need to identify the several kinds of triangles.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html

Suppose your table has a, b and c columns for the triangle sizes, the solution is this:

```
select 
  case 
    when a + b < c or a + c < b or b + c < a then 'Not a triangle'
    when a = b and b = c then 'Equilateral'
    when a = b or a = c or b = c then 'Isosceles'
    when a <> b and b <> c then 'Scalene'
  end triangle_type
from table
```

Comment: o common brother this is not a homework ,this is just a problem which i found while practicing SQL.   By the way thanks for the help.

Comment: MySQL does have an IF though. Two if you count the function and the logical control syntax used in Stored Routines.

Comment: @Uueerdo: indeed, you are right! I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Dikshant, I didn't mean to be rude, sorry, but copying someone's else question for us to answer is not very nice. We expect you at least write the question with your own words.

Comment: @Marcovecchio ,yep i will keep in mind in future,aplogy from my side.Now  pls help me how to approach such type of question.This something very new for me.I have just practice simple sql queries.

Comment: @Marcovecchio,will you help????

Comment: @Dikshant, I updated the answer, take a look

Comment: @Marcovecchio,Thanks brother ,I got it.Thanks once again.

Comment: @Dikshant, then please mark the answer as correct.

Comment: @Marcovecchio,please upvote the question if u downvote it.

Comment: @Marcovecchio you will never find an Equilateral ;)

Comment: @Uueerdo, indeed! Thanks for that, I fixed the answer!

Comment: @Marcovecchio,logic of isosclene and not a triangle is incorrect.

Comment: @Dikshant My geometry may be a bit rusty, what is wrong with that logic?

Comment: @Dikshant, I had to Google how to find out if a triangle is valid given the side lenghts, and I think the logic is correct. But if it's wrong, please do the fixing, the point of the anwser is to help you with SQL, not geometry.

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with other more conventional programming languages MySQL's `IF` function works similarly. The [function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) itself is fairly straightforward.

It is similar to the ternary operator available in many C style languages.

```
[condition] ? [when true] : [when false]
```

Or if you are familiar with VB, it is practically identical to it's inline if.

```
IIf([condition], [when true], [when false])
```